# index.html not showing as default page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created an **empty** Web Application in  .NET Core, in `wwwroot` I have the **index.html** which is not loading as default page, it loads only when I call it explicitly.

Here is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Here my Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You have to add

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

before `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure` method.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serve-default-documents) for more details.

Comment: Good one! You are right. It's working and the order plays a big role, what I dislike, but...

Comment: Here is additional information. For example which library to add, and which order. http://www.talkingdotnet.com/make-index-html-startup-file-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: Is there a page where we can see, which middleware has to be called when? Or, just google it all...

Comment: For my case root of problem was using UseDefaultFiles after UseMvc

Comment: Working through [a tutorial](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tutorial/bakery)  i wanted to add a html file. I first placed `foo.html` under the folder `/pages/` but it did not show up. Moving it to `/wwwroot/` did the trick.

Answer (score -12):

Another way to do it is to edit your web.config file. Add there new rules,  corresponding your needs.